# Car battery Confusion

Tags: battery, car, hyundai

The Battery provided to me in with the car is 60 Din (Ref C20 Capacity AH : 60, Charging Current A : 4)

I’m looking to change my battery as its old and giving issues.

The one which I want to go for is Exide EpiQ  which has a Higher Capacity (Ref Capacity - 68, Charging Current A : 4.7)

Will this battery work on my car? Will it damage any electrical circuits or alternator in my car?

Does having a higher capacity mean it is sending higher amps to my car?

Answer (score 1):

As far as the charging circuit and alternator, this battery shouldn't cause your car any issues.

Your potential issue with getting a battery of a different size is its physical size and how the posts are situated on the battery itself. As long as it will physically fit into the battery box dimensions without interfering with anything and the posts are in the right location (and are the right type of posts), there shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I’m confused about 1 thing. What is charging current. If both the battery’s have Ref Capacity - 68, But 1 battery has a Charging current of 4A and the Other has a Charging Current of 4.7 A Does that mean the 2nd battery which has a higher charging current will take longer time to charge Or The duration taken by both the batteries to charge from 0 - 100 % would be same. It’s confusing about that

Comment: @Mohur The charge current is the manufacturer's recommended amount of current used to charge the battery to charge it as quickly as possible without causing damage to the battery. The larger capacity battery can handle a higher charging current without being damaged. Larger batteries take longer to charge at the same charging current. At 4 Amps the 60AH battery will take 15 hours for 0-100%. At 4 Amps the 68 AH battery will take 17 hours. At the rated 4.7 Amps however, the 68 AH battery will take ~14.5 hours. That is charging time for flat battery. Hopefully your battery never gets there.